# HTML/CSS align multiple elements within div

Tags: html, css

I wonder how to align three elements in one div. Basically, it should look like this
[image]

Solved.
For future readers, the solution for my problem looks like this

```html
<div style="text-align: center;">
  <span style="float: left;">LEFT</span>
  <span style="margin: auto;">CENTER</span>
  <span style="float: right;">RIGHT</span>  
</div>
```

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/n9h60p7z/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using **`float:left`** and **`float:right`** for left and right see this fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/u924gptz/

Comment: Thank you very much for your prompt reaction.

Answer (score 3):

```css
.container{
  display: flex; // working with all latest browsers
  display: -webkit-flex;  // for old version of safari
  display: -ms-flex; // for old versions of IE
  justify-content: space-between;
}
.container span{
  flex: 1;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <span>LEFT</span>
  <span>CENTER</span>
  <span>RIGHT</span>  
</div>
```

The best thing is if you are adding more data inside `container`. it will give equal spacing. And inline styling is not a better option

[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/htcxf9L5/) here

Comment: This is the best solution, but you should add a fallback because of browser support

Answer (score 1):

Please do follow certain things like not have any styles inline

```
.wrapper {
    text-align: center;
}
.left {
    float:left;
}
.center {
    margin: auto;
}
.right {
    float: right;
}


<div class="wrapper">
  <span class="left">LEFT</span>
  <span class="center">CENTER</span>
  <span class="right">RIGHT</span>  
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use DIVs instead of spans and this simple CSS for the container element:

```
.x { 
      display: flex; 
      justify-content: space-between;
    }
```

`display: flex` does the equal distirbution, `justify-content: space-between;` makes the outmost elements align at the borders.

```css
.x { 
  display: flex; 
  justify-content: space-between;
}
```

```html
<div class="x">
  <div>LEFT</div>
  <div>CENTER</div>
  <div>RIGHT</div>  
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

All 3 spans should have separate stylings.
Here:

```
<div style="text-align: center;">
  <span style="float: left;">LEFT</span>
  <span style="margin: auto;">CENTER</span>
  <span style="float: right;">RIGHT</span>  
</div>
```

This should do it.

Answer (score 0):

well there are a number of ways to do this. but you could use something like this

```css
div { display:flex; align-items: center;}
span:first-child {float:left;}
span:nth-child(2) {margin:0 auto}
span:last-child {float:right}
```

```html
<div>
      <span>LEFT</span>
      <span>CENTER</span>
      <span>RIGHT</span>  
    </div>
```